# Qt Virtual Keyboard orientation

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtvirtualkeyboard

I am trying to use the Qt Virtual keyboard in my application and one of the things that would be nice to have is to have the keyboard come from the right side of the screen and not basically align itself to use the full available width but say half the width.

Now looking at the `InputPanel` documentation it says:

> The keyboard size is automatically calculated from the available
>   width; that is, the keyboard maintains the aspect ratio specified by
>   the current style. Therefore the application should only set the width
>   and y coordinates of the InputPanel, and not the height.

So, in my application I would like to set the width (say to half the screen width) but that means that the height is calculated by default and the keyboard is too small. What I would like to do is to set the width and ask the keyboard to ignore the aspect ratio settings and basically set the height to the parent height. This is, of course, at odds with the documentation quoted above and I wonder if someone knows of a workaround for this?

My InputPanel looks like:

```
InputPanel {
    id: inputPanel
    z: 89
    y: active ? parent.height - height : parent.height + 100
    width: 300
    anchors.right: parent.right
}
```

With my current code (with qt numeric keypad enabled) it looks like the attached image:

[image]

What I would like is to stretch the keyboard in the vertical direction to use the height of the parent window. Currently, it calculates the height based on the current aspect ratio which makes the input panel too small for my needs.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're going for here?

Comment: @Mitch I edited the question to include a screenshot

Comment: @Mitch I think the only way to do it to write your own keyboardStyle. I am looking into that now.

Comment: @Luca Did you manage to solve this issue? If yes, how did you do that? Thanks.